# How get triangles with Delaunay tirangulation in 3D for surface reconstruction?

Tags: surface, delaunay

The output of the Delaunay triangulatation will be a set of tetrahedra. I would like to generate a 3D triangular surface mesh. How can I get the triangles which form the surface?

Answer (score 0):

The only surface you can reconstruction from a Delaunay triangulation is the convex hull. You might be more interested in a surface reconstruction algorithm
like [this one](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/) (for close model, with new nodes created) or [that one](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/index.html#Chapter_Advancing_Front_Surface_Reconstruction) (for open models only using input points).